# Open Port 25 CentOS 6 with Plesk

Tags: centos

I've bought an unmanaged dedicated server. Mainly to help me learn.

My email isn't working and the host support have told me I that need to open port 25 to enable smtp. Note I can't send or receive email.

I've used SSH to login and I've tried a few of the sample snippets of code from this forum but I just get a command not found back.

My server is running centOS and it has a Plesk GUI.

I've connected to the server using ssh root@myipaddress

Comment: There are few questions to be asked here: How is your email not working ? What did you try and see failing ? Could you please explain ? Also, from another server on the internet, please run this command `telnet your_ip_address 25` and update your original post with the output you see on the terminal window.

Comment: Thanks! I just can't send or receive email. It just won't connect to the server. I have just used that telnet command and I have received back "Unable to connect to remote host"

Comment: On the local host, i.e. your new centos system, please run this command and post the output: `netstat -an | grep 25` this will show you if anything is listening on the smtp port, i.e. port 25, on your server. If it is not, this means you can not receive email on this server.

Comment: I get the following: [See code here](http://qwerty-demos.co.uk/test.html)

Comment: You don't have anything listening on port 25, which is SMTP port. So, there is no way that someone can send an email to your server and you receive it. Answer below, assumes that you have a running mailserver and trying to help you let the SMTP traffic pass through the iptables server based firewall. But you are not at that stage yet. You need to configure a mail server. Unless your sole purpose it to send and receive email with this server, it is not a good start point, learning about Linux. A badly configured mail server can be a honey pot for spammers and you find yourself in hot water

Comment: if your heart is set on setting up mail server, see this page first http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-mail-server-in-centos-6/

Comment: Thanks man. I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help. The main purpose of the server is to host client websites. Many of my clients have their own email setups but some of my smaller clients like to use the pop email that comes with the hosting. At the moment I have created a subscription in Plesk for their hosting and set up email for them again in Plesk. So are you saying to get this email working I'd need to install an email server? Does this have to be achieved via SSH? How do you think I should proceed?

Comment: The page I gve the link for, shows you how to do it while you are connected via ssh. There are other methods as well, but I am old school and like to do everything possible on the terminal screen.

Comment: My host is saying that the mail software is installed and that I just need to open port 25. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: The I'm not sure what's going on but they have finally opened port 25 for me and I am now finally able to receive email. Thanks so much for your help mate. Not sure why it looked like there was no mail server.  they posted this  is `cooper@new-access ~]$ telnet 212.48.**.230 25
Trying 212.48.**.230...
Connected to green6***.server-cp.com (212.**.74.230).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 green6***.server-cp.com ESMTP Postfix`

Answer (score 0):

The command to check if 25 is open:

`Telnet <your-IP> 25`

If it allows it, the port is open and that's not your problem.

If connection is refused, do the following:

`sudo vi /etc/iptables.test.rules`

Check that there is an entry like this:

`# Allows SMTP access
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT`

If not, change it using vi commands. If you're new, remember `i` goes into insert mode to use standard keyboard and `:wq!` saves when you're done.

Next, apply the rules you just wrote.

`sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.test.rules`

Check to make sure the rules are applied correctly.

`sudo iptables -L`

Next, save them permanently.

`sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables.up.rules`

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. When I use the iptables.test.rules command I get no entry and just the prompt "/etc/iptables.test.rules" [New File]

Comment: Do I need to create this file and set up the ports I want open?

Comment: Run this command and let me know what you get: `netstat -a | grep 25`

This will look for all ports then filter out just the lines that include "25"

Comment: I get the following: [See code here](http://qwerty-demos.co.uk/test.html)

Comment: Doesn't look like anything is trying o connect creating a binding. Try `nc -l 25` then from a remote computer either ssh to port 25 or `nc <local $hostname> 25`

Comment: If the nc doesn't work, run this command from your CLI and try again:


`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT`
`/etc/init.d/iptables restart`

Comment: Could you please mark as "answered' if this is fixed? If it does not solve the problem, please let me know and I'd be happy to help further.